# MySQL - At least one of something and greater than between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables :

[image]

I need to retrieve the name of the sellers that have sold during January AT LEAST one product where the total amount of sales of this said product during January is greater than 1000.

I thought about starting like this :

```
SELECT c.nom, c.prenom 
FROM Commerciaux c
LEFT JOIN Ventes v ON c.id_commerciaux = v.id_commerciaux
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM Produits p, Ventes v
WHERE p.id_produits = v.id_produits
AND MONTH(v.date) = 1
GROUP BY p.nom
HAVING SUM(v.montant) > 200)
AND MONTH(v.date) = 1
GROUP BY c.nom, c.prenom
```

The SELECT in the WHERE EXISTS seems to be working, but when I have to get link the table Sellers, I don't know how to write it.

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select distinct s.name
from Sellers s,
    (   -- get all those products that qualify (more than 1000 sales)
        select product_id, sum(amount) as total 
        from Sales 
        where Month(date) = 1
        group by product_id
        having total > 1000
    ) vp,
     Sales sa 
where 
    s.id = sa.commercial_id and
    sa.product_id = vp.id and
    Month(sa.date) = 1
```

@Leo answer would return only those Sellers that have sold more than 100 of the product in January instead of returning all Sellers that have sold any amount of the product that has been sold in an amount greater than 1000 across the board.

Comment: You're right. I tried yours, but it returns two Sellers instead of the one it should.

Comment: Oh, I've thought that you were looking for all those Sellers that have sold any amount of the product in January as long as that product has been sold in an amount greater than 1000 in January regardless of the Seller. So as an example if Product1 was sold in an amount greater than 1000 in January and Seller1 has sold just 5 and Seller 2 has sold 999 I return both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested query:

```
   SELECT s.name FROM 
   (Sellers as s JOIN Sales as sp on sp.commercial_id = s.id) JOIN
   Product as p on p.id = sp.product_id
   WHERE MONTH(sp.date) = 1  AND YEAR(sp.date) = 2017 AND    
   (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Sales as sp2 WHERE sp2.commercial_id = s.id
    AND sp2.product_id = p.id
    AND MONTH(sp2.date) = 1 AND YEAR(sp2.date) = 2017) > 1000
```

First, join the three tables on foreign keys, and then run a nested query to compute amount of the selected seller on a specific product to check to pass the amount limitation.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT C.name
FROM Sales A
JOIN Product B ON A.produit_id  = B.id
JOIN Seller C ON A.commercial_id = C.id
WHERE MONTH(A.date) = 1 
HAVING SUM(A.nAmount) > 100
GROUP BY C.name
```

Comment: you need to add `product_id` into the GroupBy clause too.

Comment: Seems to be working thanks ! @OmG I did what you said too thanks